# CSS3 initial crossfade animation fades to white

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I wanted to set up a cross fading background with CSS3 and followed some instructions from http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

My animation looks like:

```
@keyframes imageAnimation {  
    0% { opacity: 1; }
   22% { opacity: 1; }
   33% { opacity: 0; }
   89% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

The crossfade works, but the problem is, that the first animation loop isn't working as expected. I set up a little jsfiddle example to reproduce my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/5j7nrf7y/

As you can see, the first loop from red fades to white and then jumps to yellow. After the first complete loop, the crossfade works fine from red to yellow.

What is wrong with the first animation-loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting your starting opacity to 1:

https://jsfiddle.net/5j7nrf7y/1/

```
.container > figure { 
    ....
    opacity:1;
    ....
}
```

I believe since they initially start at 0, you see that jump because they are hidden before the next animation begins

Comment: Perfect! Sometimes it's that easy :) Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using several animations, delayed in the time, you have always to be careful about the first loop. Since the animation is delayed, the element will be in the initial state for some time. If the value asigned doesn't match the value that would need to have per the animation, you have this issue.

A way to solve this issue that I find easier than checking the initial values is setting negative values for the delay.

If you subtract the total duration of the animation from the delay, the elements will start the animation with the correct values, automatically.

On a side note, you don't need moz prefixes for animations.

```css
.container > figure {
  animation-name: imageAnimation;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 27s;

  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /*color: transparent;*/
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container > figure:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: calc(18s - 27s);
  animation-delay: calc(-9s);
  animation-delay: calc(18s - 27s);
  background-color: #0ff;
}

.container > figure:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: calc(9s - 27s);
  animation-delay: calc(-18s);
  animation-delay: calc(9s - 27s);
  background-color: #ff0;
}

.container > figure:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  background-color: #f00;
}

@keyframes
imageAnimation {  0% {
 opacity: 1;
}
 22% {
 opacity: 1;
}
 33% {
 opacity: 0;
}
 89% {
 opacity: 0;
}
 100% {
 opacity: 1;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<figure></figure>
<figure></figure>
<figure></figure>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. this is not working. it fades from red to white and stays white until it fades to red after a long time.

Comment: You are right, FF seems to have a problem with the calc in the delay ... I have added another line with the net value and now seems to work